# Unable to connect python container to activeMQ Artemis container

Tags: python, docker, activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

My end goal is to have several Python containers running different processes communicate to each other via an ActiveMQ Artemis container. I'm new to all of this, so as a start, I'm just trying to get a proof of concept running.

I followed instructions from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iy5B72rPG4) to build my image of Artemis and everything jives nicely there. I also followed [this tutorial](https://ameyanekar.medium.com/create-an-activemq-client-using-python-c532b6f91074) to get started sending messages via stomp to Artemis. When I run this script locally (from PyCharm) while my Artemis container is up and running, I can see in the web console that there is a new generated queue from the python script. However, when I containerize the same Python script, I get an error

```
Could not connect to host localhost, port 61613
Could not connect to host localhost, port 61613
Could not connect to host localhost, port 61613
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/./main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sendAMessage
  File "/code/sendAMessage.py", line 30, in <module>
    conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stomp/connect.py", line 164, in connect
    self.transport.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 109, in start
    self.attempt_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 819, in attempt_connection
    raise exception.ConnectFailedException()
```

I tried setting up a network in docker and putting both containers onto it.
I'm running my python container using

```
docker run --rm --net my-network -p 5000:5000 myimage
```

I have a feeling I'm incorrectly exposing a port, or something silly like that, but I'm just not quite familiar enough with containers to know where to start looking.

Comment: `Could not connect to host localhost` - `localhost` inside of the container won't resolve to your IP (unless you're running the container connected to the `host` network). If you're running the services in the same `docker network` then you should be able to resolve the containers by container name (or service name if you're using docker-compose to orchestrate the containers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

masseyb's answer helped point me the right way.

The way I fixed it was getting the IP address of my ActiveMQ container (docker network inspect) and putting that in the .py script instead of 'localhost'.

```
hosts = [('172.19.0.2', 61613)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The python script is working from your local host because the `-p 5000:5000` parameter exposes the port 5000 of the ActiveMQ Artemis container on the localhost.
To reach the ActiveMQ Artemis container from another container in the same docker network (`--net my-network`) the python script should use the ActiveMQ Artemis container name (`--name my-artemis`), i.e.

```
docker run --rm --name my-artemis --net my-network -p 5000:5000 myimage
```

***Docker makes deploying microservice applications very easy but it has some limitations for a production environment. I would take a look to the open source [ArtemisCloud.io](https://artemiscloud.io/) project, it is a collection of container images that provide a way to deploy the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Broker on Kubernetes.***